# EMAIL: After I press "Send"email, screen empties and email isn't sent

Tags: email, conga

this is weird and I hope you guys can help me.

- Sandbox - email is activated
- using URL to get to this screen (via Conga Composer)
- Pressing "send", empties the screen and changes URL.

Pictures and URL to make things more clear.

Page 1:
URL: **DOMAIN**/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?doc_id=015g0000000cwRCAAY&p2_lkid=003g000000R2Eyq&p3_lkid=001g000000QPAE6&template_id=00Xg0000000MsBN

[image]

When I press "Send", it immediately refreshes to this page and URL, without sending email.

**Domain**//_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor

[image]

what gives?

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out.  When I arrive to that page, my domain is:

-https://SOMETHING--poc--c.cs17.visual.force.com

But when it gets blanked out, it is:

-https://SOMETHING--poc.cs17.my.salesforce.com

When I use that URL, plus all my other parameters, it sends the email.  Now I have to figure out how to give it the second domain instead.